# Android: limit selected item on list to 1 in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i have a ListView and i want to select one item from the list and change the background color to gray. Currently, if i select one from the list, i can also select another... i want to limit my selection to 1  and when i select an item i will not be able to select another item.

here's my code:

```
myadapter =  new MyAdapter(Main.this, object_list);
mylist.setAdapter(myadapter);

mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

            }
        });
```

Comment: before painting the item, you would have to reset the background color of all other items, so it would still be painted only one item at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` to your `ListView` in your layout-xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a custom adapter and so you can use the method `isEnabled(int position)` of the baseadapter class and make the item that is clicked enabled and the remaining disabled. But i wonder what's the reason for making the other items unfit for selection.

Comment: hi G_S! the list contains names.. i need to assign one name to a job and in order to assign one, i need to select one from the list and click the assign button. to undo my selection, fyi, i have another setOnItemLongCLick to remove the color of the highlighted one.

Comment: ok that's fine ... try checking out the method isEnabled() for the item you need to make it enable and make others disable .. or even try the other solution if that's helpful to you